# Which locality (if any) uses "at the roundabout, take the second exit"

Tags: word-choice

I'm a regular user of Google Maps on Android and use the directions feature with voice directions. Here in New Zealand, roundabouts are common.

Google maps uses the following directions for "classic" "plus shaped" roundabouts with 4 roads converging at roughly 90 degrees angle each. The voice instructions don't match local language use (I'll contrast what I think is common local use in brackets):

- At the roundabout, take the first exit (turn left in the roundabout) - the local road code requires you to indicate left for this
- At the roundabout, take the second exit ( go straight through the roundabout)
- At the roundabout, take the third exit (turn right in the roundabout) - the local road code requires you to indicate right for this
- (I think I recall) At the roundabout, take the 4th exit (do a U-turn in the roundabout)

Even if a roundabout had 5 or more roads converging, I believe people would say "go slight/half-left, left/hard left, slight/half right, right/hard right in the roundabout.

Is the language used in Google Maps Voice directions common in any english speaking locality? If yes, where?

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundabout).

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, because there is no visual aid to the instructions. Google maps voice direction is often meaningless if you can't also glance at the imagery to confirm exactly what is being said.

Comment: Saying "the 1st/2nd/etc. exit" isn't really idiomatic, but I would think for satnav purposes it's a good way to avoid any ambiguity - even English learners could follow those directions.

Comment: Yes! The goal of communication is clarity. Using 'first, second, third... exit' for the options facing a car driver at a roundabout obviates any need for further clarification.  "Half left" or "sharp right" may be more helpful in other contexts (e.g. finding the correct  footpath ahead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what is used in the UK. It's in the [Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/using-the-road-159-to-203).

It has the advantage that it's completely unambiguous, and it's easy to count exits as you're going round, particularly on large roundabouts at motorway junctions and the like. My car's satnav combines the two ("At the roundabout, turn slightly right: take the second exit.")

I suspect that Google has paired the British "roundabout" with the British numbered-exit route description. You've inherited roundabouts and Google delivers them with other colonialisms.

The US has "traffic circles", I believe; I've no idea how they determine how to navigate them, but it's likely that Google would pair the US route description with the US name for roundabouts.

Comment: France has rond-points and [carrefours] giratoires, and they talk about première sortie, deuxième sortie, etc. At rond-points, vehicles joining have priority, at giratoires vehicles already in the circle have it.

Comment: @Andrew Leach  "colonialisms"?  I assume you intend this to mean something like a feature of of a language that is adopted by the inhabitants of a colony or something like that.  But I cannot find the word 'colonialism' accounted for in that way in Merriam Webster (at least, not on the online version.  In any case, I cannot work out which version of English is being said to be using a 'colonialism' in your otherwise very clear answer.

Comment: There are quite a few roundabouts in the UK which have more than four exits; one if them, which has five exits, is in my nearest large town so I developed the habit of referring to roundabout exits by analogue clock face positions quite a long time ago as I considered that "take the two o'clock exit" was a lot clearer than "take the exit just after the straight on, not the one all the way over to the right". Since SatNavs have become common I now use the numbered exit form which is usually even easier and clearer that the clock face.

Comment: I'm in the US, and Google Maps voice directions here call them "traffic circles" and use numbered-exit descriptions. Me and my family actually call them roundabouts, not traffic circles, and I think the signs here (Kent County, Michigan) call them roundabouts too. I don't clearly remember, though.

Comment: @Tuffy Yes and No. It definitely means "of or pertaining to the colonial ruler", and is designed to be self-deprecating as we know the UK has no colonies. In foisting the language of the former ruler on New Zealand, Google is perpetuating what the UK has given up.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - Britain retains sovereignty over 14 territories outside the British Isles, although we call them 'British Overseas Territories' these days.